# Conflict between javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnection and java.mail

Tags: java, email, ssl, soap

In our system(app), we send tax document by webservices hosted by government servers. We send this documents by the following method:

```
public SOAPMessage conecta(String xmlNfedados, URL url) throws SOAPException{
    SOAPMessage res = null; 

    try {
        MimeHeaders header = new MimeHeaders();
        header.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/soap+xml");

        MessageFactory factory = MessageFactory.newInstance(SOAPConstants.SOAP_1_2_PROTOCOL);

        SOAPMessage message;
        message = factory.createMessage(header, new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlNfedados.getBytes()));
        SOAPConnection con = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance().createConnection();
        res = con.call(message, url);

        con.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return res;
}
```

and before this connection we set this properties in the jvm:

```
public void setPropertiesA1(String caminhoCertificado, String senhaCertificado, String caminhoCacerts){
    //preparar as propriedades
    Properties properties = System.getProperties();
    properties.setProperty("java.protocol.handler.pkgs",  "com.sun.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol");
    properties.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "PKCS12");
    properties.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", caminhoCertificado);
    properties.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", senhaCertificado);
    properties.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "JKS");
    properties.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", caminhoCacerts);
    properties.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit");
    properties.setProperty("com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump", "true");
    //properties.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "all");

}
```

Everything was working fine. Until we need to send and receive emails for suppliers. In the case of receiving the emails, we use the following:

```
public static Store conectar(String login, String senha)
throws NoSuchProviderException, MessagingException
{
    logger.info("Conectando ao servidor de e-mail");

    logger.info("--------------Processo de leitura iniciado-----------------");
    String imap = "imaps";
    String host = "pop.gmail.com";
    int porta = 587;
    String diretorioServidor = "Inbox";

    Properties prop = new Properties();
    //System.out.println("numero antes " + System.getProperties().size());
    Session session = Session.getInstance(prop);

    //URLName url = new URLName(imap, host, porta, diretorioServidor, login, senha);

    Store store = session.getStore("pop3s");

    store.connect(host, login, senha);
    //System.out.println("numero depois " + System.getProperties().size());
    logger.info("Conexão estabelecida com servidor IMAP.");
    return store;
}
```

the *store* object that is returned by the method *conectar* is handled by the following:

```
public static Folder recuperarCaixaEntrada(Store store)
throws MessagingException
{
    Folder folder = store.getFolder("Inbox");
    folder.open(2);

    return folder;
}
```

The messages contained in the object *folder* are handled later in the method proccessMail():

```
public FileInputStream processMail()
throws MessagingException
{
    FileInputStream anexo = null;
    try
    {
      logger.info("Quantida de de e-mails encontrados na caixa de entrada: " + this.messages.length);

     if (this.messages.length <= 0) {
        this.folder.close(true);

        this.store.close();

        System.out.println("esta conectado " + store.isConnected());
        return null;
     }

     System.out.println("Existem na caixa de entrada: " + this.messages.length + " para serem tratados!");

     System.out.println("Tratando e-mail:1 de " + this.messages.length);
     logger.info("Tratando e-mail:1 de " + this.messages.length);

     this.message = this.messages[0];
     System.out.println("Content Type: " + this.message.getContentType());

     if (!this.message.getContentType().equals("text/plain; charset=br-ascii"))
     {
       anexo = getEmail(0);
       System.out.println("Baixou anexo");
     } else {
       System.out.println("Não baixou anexo");
     }

     this.folder.close(true);

     this.store.close();
     } catch (AuthenticationFailedException e) {
       this.store.close();
       logger.error("Falha na Autentica&#65533;&#65533;o: " + e.getMessage());
     } catch (FolderClosedException e) {
       this.store.close();
       logger.error("Falha no fechamento da pasta: " + e.getMessage());
     } catch (FolderNotFoundException e) {
       this.store.close();
       logger.error("Pasta n&#65533;o encontrada: " + e.getMessage());
     } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
       this.store.close();
       logger.error("NoSuchProviderException: " + e.getMessage());
     } catch (ReadOnlyFolderException e) {
       this.store.close();
       logger.error("Pasta com permiss&#65533;o de somente leitura: " + e.getMessage());
     } catch (StoreClosedException e) {
       this.store.close();
       logger.error("Erro ao fechar pasta auxiliar: " + e.getMessage());
     } catch (Exception e) {
       this.store.close();
       logger.error("Erro no m&#65533;todo Principal: " + e.getMessage());
       System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
  return anexo;
}
```

So, right after this proccess of receiving emails had been implemented, the sending of tax documents begin to return the following error:

```
com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Message send failed
17:37:56,434 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at      com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.call(HttpSOAPConn     ection.java:191)
17:37:56,435 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at     br.com.nfe.business.ComunicacaoReceitaBusiness.conecta(ComunicacaoReceitaB    usiness.java:205)
17:37:56,436 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at br.com.nfe.business.ComunicacaoReceitaBusiness.criaConexao(ComunicacaoReceitaBusiness.java:39)
17:37:56,436 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at br.com.nfe.business.EmissaoReceitaBusiness.emissaoNfe(EmissaoReceitaBusiness.java:46)
17:37:56,437 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at br.com.coliseu.nfe.business.NfeBusiness.emitirNota(NfeBusiness.java:1739)
17:37:56,437 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at br.com.coliseu.controller.NotaSaidaController.emitir(NotaSaidaController.java:1023)
17:37:56,438 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
17:37:56,439 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
17:37:56,439 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
17:37:56,440 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
17:37:56,440 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.ExecuteMethodInterceptor.intercept(ExecuteMethodInterceptor.java:61)
17:37:56,441 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.execute(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:54)
17:37:56,441 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:54)
17:37:56,442 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.execute(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:56)
17:37:56,443 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:54)
17:37:56,443 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.LazyInterceptorHandler.execute(LazyInterceptorHandler.java:61)
17:37:56,444 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:54)
17:37:56,444 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at br.com.coliseu.interceptor.LoginInterceptor.intercept(LoginInterceptor.java:92)
17:37:56,445 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.execute(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:54)
17:37:56,446 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:54)
17:37:56,446 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.execute(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:56)
17:37:56,447 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:54)
17:37:56,447 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.ExceptionHandlerInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionHandlerInterceptor.java:71)
17:37:56,448 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.execute(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:54)
17:37:56,448 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:54)
17:37:56,449 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.FlashInterceptor.intercept(FlashInterceptor.java:83)
17:37:56,450 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.execute(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:54)
17:37:56,450 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:54)
17:37:56,451 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.ParametersInstantiatorInterceptor.intercept(ParametersInstantiatorInterceptor.java:93)
17:37:56,451 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.LazyInterceptorHandler.execute(LazyInterceptorHandler.java:59)
17:37:56,452 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:54)
17:37:56,452 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.InstantiateInterceptor.intercept(InstantiateInterceptor.java:48)
17:37:56,453 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.execute(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:54)
17:37:56,454 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:54)
17:37:56,454 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.ResourceLookupInterceptor.intercept(ResourceLookupInterceptor.java:69)
17:37:56,455 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.execute(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:54)
17:37:56,455 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:54)
17:37:56,456 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.execute(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:56)
17:37:56,457 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:54)
17:37:56,457 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.EnhancedRequestExecution.execute(EnhancedRequestExecution.java:44)
17:37:56,458 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at br.com.caelum.vraptor.VRaptor$1.insideRequest(VRaptor.java:91)
17:37:56,458 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at     br.com.caelum.vraptor.ioc.spring.SpringProvider.provideForRequest(SpringProvider.java:58)
17:37:56,459 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at br.com.caelum.vraptor.VRaptor.doFilter(VRaptor.java:88)
17:37:56,459 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
17:37:56,460 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
17:37:56,460 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.obtainContent(SiteMeshFilter.java:129)
17:37:56,461 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:77)
17:37:56,462 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
17:37:56,462 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
17:37:56,463 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
17:37:56,463 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
17:37:56,464 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50)
17:37:56,464 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
17:37:56,465 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
17:37:56,465 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
17:37:56,466 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
17:37:56,467 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
17:37:56,467 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
17:37:56,468 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
17:37:56,468 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
17:37:56,469 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
17:37:56,470 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6) Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Message send failed
17:37:56,470 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
17:37:56,471 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.call(HttpSOAPConnection.java:185)
17:37:56,471 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   ... 60 more
17:37:56,472 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6) Caused by: com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Message send failed
17:37:56,472 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.post(HttpSOAPConnection.java:389)
17:37:56,473 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection$PriviledgedPost.run(HttpSOAPConnection.java:214)
17:37:56,474 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   ... 62 more
17:37:56,474 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6) Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
17:37:56,475 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
17:37:56,476 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1904)
17:37:56,476 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:279)
17:37:56,477 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:273)
17:37:56,477 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1446)
17:37:56,478 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:209)
17:37:56,478 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:913)
17:37:56,479 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:849)
17:37:56,479 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1023)
17:37:56,480 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1332)
17:37:56,480 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1359)
17:37:56,481 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
17:37:56,481 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
17:37:56,482 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
17:37:56,483 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1092)
17:37:56,483 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
17:37:56,484 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.post(HttpSOAPConnection.java:346)
17:37:56,485 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   ... 63 more
17:37:56,485 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6) Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
17:37:56,486 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:385)
17:37:56,487 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
17:37:56,488 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
17:37:56,488 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:326)
17:37:56,489 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:231)
17:37:56,489 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
17:37:56,490 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1428)
17:37:56,490 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   ... 75 more
17:37:56,491 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6) Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
17:37:56,492 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:196)
17:37:56,492 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:268)
17:37:56,493 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:380)
    17:37:56,493 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   ... 81 more
```

so, the error message is clear : *unable to find valid certification path to requested target*
For some reason our app is not finding the certificate path. However, as said before, the method *setPropertiesA1()* is called every single time a document need to be sent. Adding to this, I had checked if before the app tries to sent a document, the certificate path is ok, and it is. The properties "javax.net.ssl.keyStore" has the right value.

If someone who has a deep understanding of how this types of connections works, can give us a glimpse of solution, or point where we are doing something wrong, we would be very thankful.

I hope that the question is clear enough.

We use JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final as server application.

**UPDATE**
The problem here isn't just "missing certificate", because it wouldn't work too if we comment the code responsible for sending the emails.

Another point of clarification is, both connections are not been done at the same time, they occur one after another. More precisely, the connection of the email part before the connection of the tax document part.

The main question here is :
Why the SOAPConnection is not getting the path from the properties, after we send or receive a email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an extensive research on the matter I found the solution, which is to implement a keymanager and a trustmanager in conjunction with a sslcontext. That will be used inside a HttpsConnection object.

The method "SOAPMessage conecta(String xmlNfedados, URL url)" was refactored:

```
public String conecta(String xmlNfedados, URL url) throws SOAPException{
    String outputString = "";
    try {
        if(context != null){

            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            HttpsURLConnection httpsconn = (HttpsURLConnection) connection;

            httpsconn.setSSLSocketFactory(this.context.getSocketFactory());

            byte[] buffer = new byte[xmlNfedados.length()];
            buffer = xmlNfedados.getBytes();

            ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bout.write(buffer);

            byte[] b = bout.toByteArray();

            httpsconn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/soap+xml");
            httpsconn.setRequestMethod("POST");

            httpsconn.setDoOutput(true);
            httpsconn.setDoInput(true);

            OutputStream out = httpsconn.getOutputStream();

            out.write(b);
            out.close();

            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(httpsconn.getInputStream());

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);

            String responseString = "";

            while((responseString = in.readLine()) != null){
                outputString = outputString + responseString;
            }

            /*MimeHeaders header = new MimeHeaders();
            header.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/soap+xml");

            MessageFactory factory = MessageFactory.newInstance(SOAPConstants.SOAP_1_2_PROTOCOL);

            SOAPMessage message;
            message = factory.createMessage(header, new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlNfedados.getBytes()));
            SOAPConnection con = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance().createConnection();
            res = con.call(message, url);*/

        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException("SSContext não inicializado");
        }

        //con.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return outputString;
}
```

The method "getsslContext" is responsible for initialize the sslContext:

```
@Override
public SSLContext getSslContext(String camingoCert, String caminhoCacerts, String senhaCertificado){
    SSLContext sc = null;
    try {
        sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        KeyManager[] km = getKeyManager(camingoCert, senhaCertificado);
        TrustManager[] tm = getTrustManager(caminhoCacerts);

        sc.init(km, tm, null);

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sc;
}
```

Here follows the "getKeyManager":
    private KeyManager[] getKeyManager(String caminhoCert, String senha){
        KeyManagerFactory kmf = null;

```
    try {
        kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance( KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm() );
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance( "pkcs12" );
        ks.load(new FileInputStream( caminhoCert ), senha.toCharArray() );

        kmf.init( ks, senha.toCharArray() );

    } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (CertificateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnrecoverableKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return kmf.getKeyManagers();
}
```

and the "getTrustManager":

```
private TrustManager[] getTrustManager(String caminhoCacerts){
    TrustManagerFactory tmf = null;
    try {

        tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        KeyStore ts = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        ts.load(new FileInputStream(caminhoCacerts), SENHACACERTS.toCharArray());
        tmf.init(ts);

    } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (CertificateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return tmf.getTrustManagers();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a connection with on a secured http connection (https) you need to import the client certificate of your backend service to your java key store file (jks) which will be use to encrypt the message you are sending through the wire, which only can be decrypted using the backend private key. So as in the error you don't have that client certificate in your local java key store file. Import it to your local jks file and it will work.

Following command can be use to import a client certificate to your java key store. [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/toolsign/rstep2.html) is the java documentation for it.

```
keytool -import -alias susan -file Example.cer -keystore exampleraystore.jks
```

If you don't have a certificate you can export a client certificate by following command. [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/toolsign/step5.html) is the java documentation for it.

```
keytool -export -keystore examplestore -alias signFiles -file Example.cer
```

**[UPDATE]**
My above statement valid if it complain for missing certificate. But in your case it is a [bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8062602) in openJDK where you may need to get the latest fix version of openJDK or move to OracleJDK.

Comment: is it really necessary to do so? Because the code that send the tax document worked for years without doing this. The error just started happening after the mail service went on. If we disable that code responsible for emails it starts to work again, that is the thing that I don't understand.

Comment: Thank you for your attention here @Eranda! But it is not a bug. Because if so, it wouldn't work in the first place by commenting the part of sending emails. And it is not just a "missing certificate", I checked the property before the proccess of sending a tax document. But thank's again :)

Comment: But above exception says that exception occurred on "res = con.call(message, url);" line.

Comment: yes yes! the error happens there. But again, if I said that when we coment the code related to the part where the app receive email, and by doing so the app don't make any connection to gmail, and the error no longer occur?

Comment: This is valid when it sending a message. The message will be encrypted using the certificate you have installed and when the program tries to get the certificate it failed.